# CGIImage is nil after a segue

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, segue

I have a `prepareForSegue` that passes an image like this to the next `viewController`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  WizardPreview *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
  controller.myPicture = myPicture;
}
```

On the `viewWillAppear` of the `viewController` being presented I have a like like this

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [self.myPicture CGImage];
```

the result is nil

The strange part is that `self.myPicture` is not nil, but `self.myPicture.CGImage` is.

Any reason for that?

NOTE: `myPicture` is not nil when it is passed and even from `viewWillAppear`, I test and I see that `self.myPicture` is not nil.

NOTE 2: this is a code compiled for iOS 7 running on an iPhone with iOS 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted enough code to say for sure. The three most likely options are:

1. If `myPicture` is `nil` in the `prepareForSegure:sender:` method
2. If `WizardPreview`'s `myPicture` property is `weak`
3. If the `UIImage` is not backed by a `CGImage` (for example, if it's backed by a `CIImage`)

If #3 is true, you can create a `CGImage` directly from a `CIImage` ([sample code here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14402413/1445366)).

Comment: 1. myPicture is not nil when passed and even from `viewWillAppear`.  2. no it is strong. 3. what do you mean?   ... I have added more info to the question.  The strange part is `self.myPicture` is not nil... `self.myPicture.CGImage` is.

Comment: Not all `UIImage`s have a `CGImage`.

Comment: Now you crumbled my world... what??????????? how do I fix that? This UIImage was created from a CCImage.

Comment: Is the `CIImage` property nil also?

Comment: this phrase of yours "Not all UIImages have a CGImage", solved the problem. I changed the code to create a CGImage directly from the CIImage and it worked. Please add this phrase to your answer, so I can accept that.