# UIImage Not Filling UIImageView with AspectFit

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am making a music player app and I want A gaussian blur on the album cover image so I implemented the code that follows but the image is not filling the `UIImageView`:

```
let bgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.width))
let image = CIImage(image: (currentSong?.info.albumCover)!)
let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
blurFilter?.setValue(image, forKey: "inputImage")
let resultImage = blurFilter?.value(forKey: "outputImage") as! CIImage
let blurredImage = UIImage(ciImage: resultImage)
bgView.image = blurredImage
bgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
self.addSubview(bgView)
```

I thought that changing the content mode to `scaleAspectFit` would fix that but it did not

Update:

The Code below gives me the desired image size but without the blur. is there any reason applying a blur would cause the size of the image to be different?

```
let bgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.width))
    let image = CIImage(image: (currentSong?.info.albumCover)!)
    bgView.image = image
    bgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    self.addSubview(bgView)
```

Comment: scaleAspectFit will maintain the ratio and " Any remaining area of the view’s bounds is transparent." from apple document. you may try scaleToFill?

Comment: @Surely I just tried that and got the same result. The aspect ratio for the image and the view are the same as well so that would not make a difference.

Comment: Can you give me specific sizes/extents? UIImage, CIImage, UIImageView - all three?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `UIImage` backed by a `CGImage` instead of a `CIImage`.
Try to render your `CIImage` into a `CGImage` and create your `UIImage` from that `CGImage`. See [Getting a CGImage from CIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402413/getting-a-cgimage-from-ciimage) to know how to do this.