# Converting a UIimage to a CIimage and back to a UIimage results in a white/blank display

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can display the UIImage that I load but when I convert it to a CIimage and back it fails to display correctly.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var stateString = "abc";
    @State var stateImage = UIImage(named: "Lenna")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(uiImage: stateImage!)
            Text(stateString)
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear(){
            guard let uiimage = UIImage(named: "Lenna") else {return};
            guard let ciimage = CIImage(image: uiimage) else {return};
            
            stateString = "past guard"
            stateImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciimage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a completely futile exercise. What's the point? A UIImage in general is _not_ backed by a CIImage and cannot be converted to and from a CIImage. You can usually round-trip between a UIImage and _CGImage_ pretty well, but a CIImage is a completely different sort of thing.

Comment: @matt It is a completely futile exercise. I am just starting to play around with this and wanted to be able to load images as placeholders for what will eventually be images captured by the camera. Is there a better way to get placeholder CIimages besides loading them from the device?

Comment: CIImages are for use with Core Image. They are not something that is ever displayed so you don't need one as a placeholder. Images captured by the camera are not CIImages either.

Comment: @matt Sorry I was unclear, I am making a utility that will operate on a CIImage. Eventually, these will come directly from the camera. In the mean time I wanted to load images, process them as I would, and then display them. I figured a good starting point would be to make sure that I could convert to a CIImage make no changes and convert it back into a UIImage so that I knew that it would work without me making any changes to CIImage. So this is just a learning exercise. Is there a way for me to imitate an image captured by the camera that I should be using instead?

Answer (score 2):

As Matt says in the comments, this is sort of silly. Are you just doing this as a learning exercise?

I've converted `UIImages` to `CIImage`s, applied Core Image filters to them, and then converted them back to `UIImage`s (or rather, from `CIImage` to `CGImage` to `UIImage`.)

UIImage is backed by a `CGImage`, and if you have a `UIImage` you can get to it's backing `CGImage` with a property of the `UIImage`. You can also easily create a `UIImage` from a `CGImage`.

`CIImage` is used by Core Image, which is cross-platform. It interacts with CGImage, not UIImage. You'll need to convert from `UIImage` to `CGImage`, and then from `CGImage` to `CIImage`.

CIImage has an initializer that takes a `CGImage` as input:

```
init(cgImage image: CGImage)
```

And then in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45815004/205185) there is a function that will convert a `CIImage` back to a `CGImage`.

That function (from the link, not my code) looks like this:

```
func convertCIImageToCGImage(inputImage: CIImage) -> CGImage? {
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(inputImage, from: inputImage.extent) {
        return cgImage
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Duncan. I am trying to make a utility that will make changes to a image captured by the camera. I wanted to avoid actually capturing the image yet and instead just load the images from device and operate on that. Is there a better way for me to do that than converting from a CGImage to a CIImage?

Comment: @P.Bjur did you check if your UIImage's `ciImage` property is `nil`?

Comment: So you want to initially process images loaded from the user's camera roll and apply core image filters to them?  Converting your images from CGImage to CIImage should work fine.